# What are some sources for WinBolo brains and borgs that have current links?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, bolo

All of the winbolo links for downloading resources seem broken. Does anyone know of any sources for winbolo brains, borgs, and the like that has current links?

Comment: Are winbolo brains compatibile with original brains?

Comment: That's a great question. I have no idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple original ones downloadable from [this site](http://www.umich.edu/~archive/mac/game/war/bolo/brain/).

For winbolo, I found [this site](http://www.lgm.com/winbolo/) which lists five, the middle three are still downloadable. Ryan2 seems to be a popular one that is hard to find, due to the home site being down. However, two versions of the Ryan2 brain can be found [here](http://www.angelfire.com/extreme3/nananovace/winbolodownloads/) (angelfire site FTW).

Let us know which ones work!

Comment: Will try these out and upvote once I've confirmed that they work. :)